# I need to reload the form on button click

Tags: c#, sql

I have been trying different methods these past days to overcome this problem but I haven't found a reliable solution to my problem. The problem is I have to reload the form in case the first time the application starts and the components are not filled up due to network or SQL connectivity issue.  As of now, everyone is closing the application and starting again because the first time they start the application the components were empty.

Below is the code I'm using.

```
private void Reports_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //START:
    try
    {
        RevenueDate_dt = func.getResult(dateQuery);
        foreach (DataRow dr in RevenueDate_dt.Rows)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["Global_Period_Month"].ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //goto START;
        MessageBox.Show("Network is too slow! Please close the application and try again later");
    }
}
```

Function:

```
public DataTable getResult(string query)
{
    //con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

I have placed a retry button on my form so if the first time the component is not filled with the data so everyone can use the retry button to load the component instead of closing the whole application and starting again.

Comment: (Did you mean "instead of" rather than "despite", i.e. "so everyone can use the retry button to load the component instead of closing the whole application and starting again" ?)  ... so, do you have a button click event handler method?

Comment: I would focus on the network problem, especially since this looks like a local network.

Comment: @criticalfix Yes instead of... umm no I don't have button click event handler method.

Comment: @LarsTech The thing is when I'm trying to access the table through SQL it's working perfectly but throwing error in application.

Comment: See csharpbd's answer below.  That retry_Click() method is an event handler.  You have to go to the button's properties and tell it that a click event is supposed to be handled by this method.

Comment: Don't do what you are doing in the load event — it can swallow exceptions.  Use the form's constructor.  You will have to document what specific error you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill component by calling `Reports_Load` `event` in your `retry button`. `Reports_Load` will fill your component. Check below code.

CODE:

```
private void retry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Reports_Load(null, null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @csharpbd it works perfectly :) first time it didn't fill but when I used your code It works :)

Comment: @SohaibAkhtar Is the load event wired up?